# Programmatically clicking on web page image using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I've got a web page with an image, set up as follows:

```
<a id="Repeater_Rediger_0" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("Repeater$ctl02$Rediger", "", true, "", "", false, true))">
<img src="/Grafik/Zoom.gif" border="0">
```

I want to click on the image programmatically, but my code doesn't produce the desired result with either of my attempts:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Repeater_Rediger_0").Click

WebBrowser1.Document.All("Repeater_Rediger_0").Click
```

Comment: Why the Java tag ? You probably mean javascript

Comment: What's the actual issue you are having ?

Comment: Yes I mean javascript
I use VBA to open a web pages to import some informations to Excel.

My problem is that I cant find out how to click on the button.

Its not a public web page so I cant link to it.

Comment: have you tried `.form.submit` can you show a touch more html so we can see if it resides in a form or not etc.?

Comment: or `.fireevent("click")`

Comment: Retagged, fixed typographical error, removed extraneous or redundant information.

Comment: Please show more HTML. The above is insufficient.